"Invalid_grant" error after using "change_current_realm()" in keycloak-python
I have 401: b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}' error after I switch realm with change_current_realm() function from "master" to "new-sso" realm.
Here is the full code:
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenIDConnection

server_url = "http://localhost:8080/"
new_sso_relam = "new-sso"

admin_username = 'admin'
admin_password = 'admin'
admin_client = 'admin-cli'
master_realm = "master"

keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(server_url=server_url, 
                                                username=admin_username, 
                                                password=admin_password, 
                                                client_id=admin_client, 
                                                realm_name=master_realm)
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)

keycloak_admin.change_current_realm(new_sso_relam)

user_payload = {"username": "new_user",
    "enabled": True}

keycloak_admin.create_user(user_payload, exist_ok=True)  

However if before switching to "new-realm" I call keycloak_admin.get_realm(master_realm), then the code works fine and I can create user.
keycloak_admin.get_realm(master_realm)

keycloak_admin.change_current_realm(new_sso_relam)
user_payload = {"username": "new_user",
    "enabled": True}

keycloak_admin.create_user(user_payload, exist_ok=True)  

I belive the invalid_grant error indicates that after switching realms with change_current_realm(), the credentials I'm using are no longer valid for the new realm. This issue arises because the Keycloak Admin client (in this case, admin-cli) is authenticated against the "master" realm and does not automatically carry over those credentials to the "new-sso" realm.
When I call keycloak_admin.get_realm(master_realm), it seems to refresh or validate your session, allowing you to switch to the new realm successfully. However, you want to eliminate that extra step.

Can you update the question to include details on how you're using MongoDB Realm (per the tag you used). Is it perhaps authentication or Atlas Sync?

You need to add user_realm_name=master_realm in KeycloakOpenIDConnection()
keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(server_url=server_url, 
                                                username=admin_username, 
                                                password=admin_password, 
                                                client_id=admin_client, 
                                                realm_name=master_realm,
                                                user_realm_name=master_realm)

Launching Keycloak
docker-compose in here
Create new-sso realm by UI
new-sso

Demo code
create-user.py
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenIDConnection, KeycloakAdmin

server_url = "http://localhost:8080/"
new_sso_relam = "new-sso"

admin_username = 'admin'
admin_password = 'admin'
admin_client = 'admin-cli'
master_realm = "master"

keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(server_url=server_url, 
                                                username=admin_username, 
                                                password=admin_password, 
                                                client_id=admin_client, 
                                                realm_name=master_realm,
                                                user_realm_name=master_realm)

keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)

keycloak_admin.change_current_realm(new_sso_relam)

user_payload = {"username": "new_user","enabled": True}
keycloak_admin.create_user(user_payload, exist_ok=True)
print("new_user registered")

Dependency
pip install python-keycloak


Run it

Result


The concept of realms in Keycloak represents multitenancy, allowing a single Keycloak instance (including its database and Infinispan) to serve multiple companies (OAuth/OIDC servers). When you authenticate (regardless of the flow used) within a realm, the iss claim in the token will point to that realm, such as https://keycloakdomain/realms/realmname. This iss claim is crucial for token validation, and if you attempt to use the token with another realm, it should not work.
Additionally, there is a special master realm (Keycloak in newer versions). To perform administrative tasks, you can create an OIDC client in the required realm, use the client_credentials grant type to obtain a token, and then utilize it with the Admin REST API to manage users.
